# how to addition variable in less

Tags: less

I have the following =>

```
@header-height: 40;
@footer-height: 20;
```

I would like to be able to do

```
    min-height: calc(~'100% - '@header-height+@footer-height'px') !important;
```

which return me

100%-60px

but my test fail as I get

min-height: calc(100% - 40+20 'px') !important;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${var}` syntax to insert variable into less string expression:

```
min-height: ~'calc(100% - @{header-height}px - @{footer-height}px)' !important;
```

Moreover, it is better to execute the whole `calc(...)` command due `~'calc(...)'` syntax